# How do I change the location in the terminal with a custom string?

Tags: command-line, bash, paths, location

If I have a really long path to a folder, and I just want the string 'longlocation' to replace it in the terminal, I know I can edit the .bashrc file and add this command:

```
alias changelc='export PS1="longlocation"'
```

This will make the path be replaced by the string 'longlocation' whenever I enter the command 'changelc' in the terminal.

Now what I want is, if I enter the command 'changelc homefolder' then the long path be replaced by the string 'homefolder', or in general, any string that follows 'changelc'.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: @Radu no. I want the new text that replaces the path to be variable, not constant. That is the main difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Switch to a bash function:

```
function changelc {
    export PS1="$1"
}
```

And then, when tested:

```
$ changelc "rawr: "
rawr:
```